# How to change query parameters from Power BI Report for Azure Time Series Insight

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerquery, azure-timeseries-insights

I am looking for a way to show live data and data within a specific date range to Power BI Report.

#### What we tried -

1. Copied the custom query from TSI
2. Connected to Power BI
3. Added query parameters in Power BI Desktop for start and end date.

```
let
//create variables for start and end times
start = DateTime.ToText(StartDateTime),
end = DateTime.ToText(EndDateTime),

 

queryPart1 = "{""storeType"":""WarmStore"",""isSearchSpanRelative"":true,""clientDataType"":""RDX_20200713_Q"",""environmentFqdn"":""someid.env.timeseries.azure.com"",
        ""queries"":[
            {""getEvents"":
            {""searchSpan"":
            {""from"":""",
queryPart2 = start,
queryPart3 = """,""to"":""",
queryPart4 = end,
queryPart5 = """},",
queryPart6 = """timeSeriesId"":[""edgedevicename"",""sensorname""],""take"":250000}}]}",
//combine individual sections of query into one
    finalQuery = Text.Combine({queryPart1,queryPart2,queryPart3,queryPart4,queryPart5,queryPart6}),
    Source = AzureTimeSeriesInsights.Contents([JsonPayload = finalQuery])
in
    Source
```

4. Got the live data on Power BI Desktop after refreshing the queries.
5. We're also able to get the data for specific date ranges using **Edit parameters**

[image]

#### Problem

1. It only works when we're using Power BI Desktop, We want to change the query parameters from the published Report.
2. We've followed the [Power BI Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdVNkhTE21g) but was not able to see the option for **binding the parameter** to any column as shown in the image below -
   [image]

#### Question -

Does Power BI support **m query parameters** for TSI Connector? if not, are there any recommendations from Microsoft to solve the problem mentioned above?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the above scenario?

Comment: @AshokPeddakotla-MSFT I suggest posting and answer, as I have this same issue. ty!

Comment: @AshokPeddakotla-MSFT,  There is no direct way as of now to show the live data using TSI to Power BI, I've switched to Stream Analytics. But if you still want to use TSI, you can use the relative time for TSI (let's say one day), But each time to refresh the data on Power BI, you've to refresh both - the dataset and the report. Which is not a good thing. (You can only schedule 8 refreshes)